# where will I find some data on how many patents are filed in each country over the last 10-15 years, in lifesciences?

Tags: patent-applications, patent-search, data-processing-software, databases

I'm looking for some data, on how many patents, related to life science are filed each year in countries such as USA, EU, Japan, Aus, India, China, Brazil etc. I don't know Where to look for to find such data?

I'm looking for a trend over the years...

Answer (score 1):

I think any of the usual patent search sites may be able to help with this. I particularly like [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/), but patents.google.com or www.freepatentsonline.com/search.html would do as well. The secret is to use classification codes to define the field of search. Here are links for [US](https://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/selectnumwithtitle.htm) and [international](http://www.wipo.int/classifications/ipc/en/) codes. Classification codes are complex and generally more specific than "life sciences" so you'll need to think hard about what you are looking for.

You can limit your search to specific date ranges, countries and classification codes. The Lens also provides some neat graphical representations of the results you might find helpful. If you register, which is free, you can save searches and access a few additional features.

This [site](http://www.uibm.gov.it/biotech/en/dati/classifica_ls.php) has a list of life science IPC codes. In addition, I found this [paper](http://blogs.nature.com/tradesecrets/2014/12/15/university-life-science-patent-transactions) that may be of interest.

Comment: I think Classification codes would be tricky. We need to search a lot that which classification would be for life science, food and chemistry. Such as blood diagnosis might fall under A and instrument related to that fall under G.

Comment: @ASHUVERMA  perhaps, but what other solution do you propose?

Comment: The classification Codes are the best way, they are assigned by professionals already and no automatic system is yet good enough. They are of course a little problematic because they are normally not tailored to the specific search, but a few searches give a good result with few outliers

Comment: I think its not the best way to do but best option available right now is this. Further, person should need to be skilled in the art to find out best classification codes.

Comment: @ASHUVERMA  The best way right now is by definition the best way. I added some links to papers related to identifying codes relating to the life sciences.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CPC classification](http://www.cooperativepatentclassification.org/index.html;jsessionid=qxj2xkhgfca8), which is used by the EPO and USPTO, you may find groups of classification that fits into lifesciences, namely the [group C](http://www.cooperativepatentclassification.org/cpc/scheme/C/scheme-C.pdf) (Chemestry). There is no specific classification for lifesciences. Thus you have to filter what groups apply. Then you may use Esp@cenet, the biggest world repository of patent publications, and then you can filter those results by country of publication and by date.